# getting the average of four test results in C++ unless grade is out of range

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program that accepts 4 grades from the user and calculates an average
if all the test score are within a range from 0 to 100. if not than the program should display marks out of range.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int num1;
int num2;
int num3;
int num4;
float average;

int main()
{
    cin>> num1;
    cin>> num2;
    cin>> num3;
    cin>> num4;

string dontcalculateAverage();
    if  (num1 < 0 || num1 > 100)
    if  (num2 < 0 || num2 > 100)
    if  (num3 < 0 || num3 > 100)
    if  (num4 < 0 || num4 > 100)
    cout << "marks out of range"
float calculateAverage();
    if  (num1 >= 0 || num1 <= 100)
    if  (num2 >= 0 || num2 <= 100)
    if  (num3 >= 0 || num3 <= 100)
    if  (num4 >= 0 || num4 <= 100)
        average = (num1 + num2 + num3 + num4) / 4.0;
        cout << average;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: the output i'm getting is wrong. it seems to calculate the average either way if the grade is out of range or not.

Comment: well you just put a semicolon after your if statements

Comment: Please don't edit code live following answers because it makes them  irrelevant.

Comment: Bluntly, you just don't understand C++ syntax, which is a requirement in order to write C++ code that makes sense. It's not clear what you think `string dontcalculateAverage();` means or why you thought those four `if` statements would somehow "connect" to control whether the following statements would execute or not, but that's just not how C++ works. You can't make things up and expect them to work. Learn C++ syntax and use only the syntax you've learned. Otherwise, there's no hope it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You get average no matter what because all your `if`s have empty statements.

```
if  (num1 < 0 || num1 > 100); <-
```

Do not put a semi colon after condition, since it means empty statement.

Also you probably want to take a look at boolean logic and block statement.

Comment: +1 The primary error with the OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that need to be fixed:

```
if  (num1 < 0 || num1 > 100);
if  (num2 < 0 || num2 > 100);
if  (num3 < 0 || num3 > 100);
if  (num4 < 0 || num4 > 100);
```

Those ifs are useless, basically if it is out of range, then do nothing. You may want to change it such that

```
if  (num1 < 0 || num1 > 100
    || num2 < 0 || num2 > 100 
    || num3 < 0 || num3 > 100
    || num4 < 0 || num4 > 100)
```

Then it will print the statement `out of range`.
Else, calculate the average.

And what do you mean by?

```
string dontcalculateAverage();
float calculateAverage();
```

Third, remember that integer division yields integer, even though the result is float. To overcome this, use `4.0` instead of `4` when dividing. You can also typecast `(float)` for the summation of `num1 + num2 + num3 + num4` as well.

Comment: thanks guys that was more than helpfull

Answer (score 0):

The output you are getting is wrong because you are using integer division. Change 4 to `4.0` to fix to double division:

```
average = (num1 + num2 + num3 + num4) / 4.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look very closely at the if statements' bodies and what is happening versus the intention.  For example, the intention is:

```
string dontcalculateAverage()
{
    string sOut;
    if  (    (num1 < 0 || num1 > 100)
          || (num2 < 0 || num2 > 100)
          || (num3 < 0 || num3 > 100)
          || (num4 < 0 || num4 > 100)
        )
        sOut = "marks out of range";

    return sOut;

} // end dontCalculateAverage()
```

The reality of the code following the dontcalculateAverage() function declaration inside the body of main (please correct this), is that the if statement logic is not doing anything.  The cout line always sends a string to the output stream.  Similarly, the next set of code accomplishes no range checking before performing the average.  And as others have already indicated, the average calculation line itself is in error since it is calling integer division.  At least one floating point number, usually the divisor is easiest, has to be present to force floating point division by the compiler.

Please look closely at what the compiler is saying and the C++ reference material at your disposal.